# Here API RouteMatch - Processing more than 150 waypoints in single request

Tags: here-api, here-routing

We are trying to process more than 150 waypoints in single request using HERE API routematch and it is failing due to size of the waypoints that is getting passed at single time with error 414.

Is there way we can handle waypoints more than 150 in a single request?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using POST request see please example on https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1/rme_basic

Like this bash cUrl request:

> curl
> 'https://fleet.api.here.com/v8/match/routelinks?mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&routeMatch=1&apiKey=***'
> \   -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \   -H 'Pragma: no-cache' \   -H
> 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \   -H 'Accept: application/json,
> text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' \   --data-raw
> $'LATITUDE,LONGITUDE\n53.3737131,-1.4704939\n53.3742428,-1.4677477\n53.3745646,-1.467576\n53.3758092,-1.4665675\n53.3765066,-1.4645076\n53.3750689,-1.4637029\n53.3745968,-1.4630377'
> \   --compressed

You tried to utilized GET request but there is limitation on length of string of URL.